# Rails generate scaffold creates in wrong places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate

On a fresh project, rails generate behaves strangely. I did:

```
rails new pm
cd pm/

rake db:migrate

rails generate controller home index

rails generate scaffold Entry title:string content:text date:date
```

Now my dir looks like this: What went wrong?

```
ls
app       date:date  generate  log        README    title:string
config        db     home        scaffold   tmp
content:text  doc    index     public     script    vendor
controller    Entry  lib       Rakefile   test
```

My system is an Ubuntu lucid, ruby-1.8.

```
$ gem -v 
1.3.5
```

Comment: ok i assume I did wrong as I setup up to now two projects with rails 3 and now on the older box there is rails 2.2 and generate is used differently. But going for lunch now...

Comment: someday I will try it... you can be sure.

Comment: For now I installed rubygems manually and installed rails-3 via gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to mark it answered:

For now I installed rubygems manually and installed rails-3 via gem